# Side-bar is not working on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a menu with a logo on the left and an icon for the menu on the right.When I click the icon, the menu slides in from the right side of the window and goes out when I click the icon again.The problem I have is

1) The side bar is not sliding when the logo is placed below the icon (Its working when the logo is placed above icon).

2) I want the side bar to slide from the bottom of the icon instead of sliding from the right of icon.

Im using Bootstrap 3

Code:HTML

```
<div id="wrapper" class="toggled">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#">eKincare Menu</a></li>
            <li style="color:white;">Menu Item</li>
            <li style="color:white;">Menu Item</li>
            <li style="color:white;">Menu Item</li>
            <li style="color:white;">Menu Item</li>
            <li style="color:white;">Menu Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="page-content-wrapper" style="margin:0;">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" style=";background-color:#00bcd3; !important">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="color:white;">
                        <!-- <li><img src="logo.png" alt="eKincare Logo" style="padding-top:5px;"></li> -->
                        <li>
                            <a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle">
                                <i class="icon icon-menu pull-right">
                                    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/android-user-interface-vol-1/16/38_-_menu_bar_lines_option_list_hamburger_web-128.png" width=50 height=30 style="padding-left:5px;">
                                </i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                       <li><img src="logo.png" alt="Logo"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code CSS

```
#wrapper {
    display:block;
    padding-right: 250px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    right: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: -250px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
    z-index:10;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -250px;
}
  /* Sidebar Styles */
.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding-right: 17%;
}
.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}
#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-right: 0;
}  
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
```

Code JS

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
  });
```

In the code,the commented "list-item( li )" is the logo-image which is placed before (above) menu-icon.(The same "list-item" is placed after the menu-icon and is not commented).I want the slide-bar to work when the logo-image is placed above menu-icon in the code.

Link: http://jsbin.com/wenexihuwo/edit?html,output

Sliding bar works. Its my mistake.

How can we slide menu bar from below instead of right in mobile version(like normal bootstrap navbar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the structure what you have designed. not with the li

Working code.

Removed the li as it is taking width for li and a as 100%

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper" class="toggled">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#">eKincare Menu</a></li>
            <li style="color:white;">Menu Item</li>
            <li style="color:white;">Menu Item</li>
            <li style="color:white;">Menu Item</li>
            <li style="color:white;">Menu Item</li>
            <li style="color:white;">Menu Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="page-content-wrapper" style="margin:0;">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0;">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" style=";background-color:#00bcd3; !important">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="color:white;">
                        <!-- <li><img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" style="padding-top:5px;"></li> -->



                       <li> <a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle" style="width:100px;float:right">
                                <i class="icon icon-menu pull-right">
                                    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/android-user-interface-vol-1/16/38_-_menu_bar_lines_option_list_hamburger_web-128.png" width=50 height=30 style="padding-left:5px;">
                                </i>
                            </a><img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" style="padding-top:5px;"></li> 
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Refer this link for bootstrap side menu   http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/fancy-sidebar-navigation

Answer (score 0):

This code works here, we do not have the image logo.png to "see" on the page, maybe your image is blocking the click area, to test better need the image.

put some alert('hi'); on the function to see if the clicks works and only the slides is broken...

sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Its working by clicking just above the #menutoggle element, check for the img element positioning.